# Best practice for shell input parameters?

Tags: shell, sh

I want to write a tool by using standard shell. Now I have three choices to handle the input of the user:

```
$ and loop
getopt
getopts
```

So the freshman's question is, considering the portability, which one is my best practice?

P.S. my tool has input like below:

```
mytool.sh [-fl] [-c|--conf file]
```

so, three parameters are provided:

- `-f`
- `-l`
- `-c | --conf`

Comment: Which platforms do you need to support? Linux and OS X both have bash as standard; if you require Windows users to use Cygwin, they will have bash too. I don't think other platforms are generally worth supporting.

Comment: For Linux only, but should make sure it is standard shell instead of bash specific. I have updated the question to show more details.

Comment: so actually the bash tag is not relevant to this question. I have removed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getopts` cannot do what you want, since it doesn't support "long options" like `--conf`.

`getopt` is variable; some implementations support long options, and some don't. (And some systems don't have any implementation). So I'm guessing that, since you don't want a Bash-specific solution, you also won't want to use `getopt`.

So that leaves you with writing your own loop . . . which is actually pretty ugly, especially since you don't want to use any Bash-specific features in the loop.

If it's important to you to use only portable constructs, I'd recommend eliminating support for the long option `--conf`, so you can use `getopts`. (Alternatively, you could eliminate support for the coalesced option notation `-fl`, so it's easier to write a custom loop, but that's still more work than using `getopts`.)

Comment: I believe traditional `getopts` (the builtin) is perfectly fine with option coalescing, so supporting `-fl` should be no problem. You’re right, he’d have to give up on `--conf` though.

Comment: @AaronDavies: It seems to work in Bash (though it doesn't seem to be documented, and I'm not sure how it remembers its position within the coalesced options), but POSIX doesn't specify it, so I wouldn't expect it to work in arbitrary shells.

Comment: @AaronDavies: Actually, correction: it looks like POSIX *does* specify that, in that it says that `getopts` "shall support the Utility Syntax Guidelines 3 to 10, inclusive", where Guideline #5 is "Options without option-arguments should be accepted when grouped behind one `'-'` delimiter." I'll edit my answer. Thanks!

Comment: I think `getopts` can be helpful too you can check out [Handling Command Line Arguments](http://www.shelldorado.com/goodcoding/cmdargs.html) for more info

Comment: I have been rolling my own option parsers for a long time and it's really not all that complex or ugly IMHO. If you give up the option clustering requirement (i.e. require `-f -l` as separate options instead of `-fl`) it's even simpler.

Comment: I wrote my own loop. But your answer is what I want! Thanks!

Comment: @tripleee: I generally roll my own option parsers, too, but I'm surprised at your statement that it's not ugly to support `-fl` using only portable constructs. I guess we must have different aesthetic senses. :-)

Answer (score 0):

`getopt`, meaning here the executable utility typically found as `/usr/bin/getopt` (as opposed to any builtins of the same name found in various shells) is probably your best choice for shell-agnostic long-options support. The traditional `getopts` builtin doesn't handle long options at all, and the shells which have implemented them have done it in mutually-incompatible ways.

You can of course implement completely custom option-handling logic by looping over `"$@"` yourself, but using a standard tool is generally a better idea.

Comment: I think your first paragraph is using `getopt` to mean `getopts`, and vice versa. (Though even after fixing that, I don't think it's completely correct.)

Comment: Hmm. You may be right. I'm also finding documentation online for a `/usr/bin/getopts`. Not sure how common it is though.  (I’m personally not very familiar with advanced printable options parsing—I’ve done all my recent shell scripting in ksh93, which has excellent, but completely idiosyncratic, long options support in its version of the builtin.) In any case, answer edited to reflect your comment.

Comment: “printable” is of course a typo for “portable” in my above comment.